# Making a constructor that accepts an integer array

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

How can I pass in an integer array into my constructor?

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Temperature implements Serializable
{
    private int[] temps = new int [7];
    public Temperature(int[] a)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            temps[i] = a[i];
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Temperature i = new Temperature(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
    }
}
```

---

The error given is:

```
Temperature.java:17: error: constructor Temperature in class Temperature cannot be applied to given types;
        Temperature i = new Temperature(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
                        ^
  required: int[]
  found: int,int,int,int,int,int,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Answer (score 7):

- For the current invocation, you need a `var-args constructor`
  instead. So, you can either change your `constructor` declaration to take a
  `var-arg` argument: -

  ```
  public Temperature(int... a) {
       /**** Rest of the code remains the same ****/
  }
  ```
- or, if you want to use `an array` as argument, then you need to `pass an
  array` to your constructor like this -

  ```
  Temperature i = new Temperature(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7});
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:
 new Temperature(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7})

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by the following way

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Temperature implements Serializable
{
    private int[] temps = new int [7];
    public Temperature(int[] a)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            temps[i] = a[i];
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int [] vals = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};  
        Temperature i = new Temperature(vals);
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Temperature i = new Temperature(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Temperature i = new Temperature(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
```

When you try to initialize this constructor consider it has int values you get error msg like

required: int[]
found: int,int,int,int,int,int,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Before intialize the value declare it in a separate variable

```
 import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class HashPrint implements Serializable
{
    private int[] temps = new int [7];
    public HashPrint(int[] a)
    {
        this.temps=a;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

        HashPrint i = new HashPrint(arr);
    }
}
```